# iOS PhoneGap App Submission

Tags: ios, cordova, ios7

As per the recent news Apple requires the app to be build and compiled using Xcode 5 and iOS7.
Also according to this article http://phonegap.com/blog/build/new-apple-app-store-submittal-rules/ all the PhoneGap iOS apps should be use version 2.5.0 and up.

I currently have an app with Cordova version 2.0.0. I fixed couple of issues i had in iOS7 and it compiles and works fine on iOS7.

I am confused. Do I have to update the PhoneGap/Cordova to 3.3.0 which is the latest version or updating to 2.5.0 will be fine for submitting app to app store ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the article you linked it is explained that apps built with versions of PhoneGap prior to 2.5.0 do not meet app store requirements. So there's part of the answer: you cannot submit with 2.0.0.

What 2.5.0 specifically fixes is quoted here:

```
Apps must be built for retina displays and for iPhone5 - new splash screen and icon support has been added to the config.xml to bring your apps up to date with this requirement. These changes are supported in PhoneGap 2.5.0+ only.
```

You can choose yourself whether you want to of to 3.3.0 rather than just 2.5.0 - but why would you not want to go to the latest version? Unless it breaks anything you may as well get the latest changes which presumably include the latest bug fixes too. Any reason not to go to 3.3.0?

PhoneGap 3.3.0 added support for Android 4.4 - you probably want that, right?